# most relavant UI library to display WCF data?

Tags: c#, .net

Sorry for this simple question I never wrote UI program on C# or .NET

I'm writing program from scratch.
I'm receiving data from WCF in it and need to display it to the user.
What library is better to use?
I need only general things like labels, lists, trees, combo, textboxes, pictures etc.

What options do I have?

Should I use C# at all? Probably there are other languages that can work with WCF?

Comment: "What options do I have?" winforms, webforms, raw html, razor, various xaml (wpf, silverlight, xbap, winrt, wp7), cf, mf, xna, gdi, gdi+...

Comment: WCF is *just* a comms tech - it is completely unrelated to UI

Comment: where can I read pros and cons of each of them...? i need something realiable and easy to use. portability is welcome but not mandatory

Comment: I know that WCF is unrelated to UI. But my task it to display some data that I receive via WCF. so WCF is mandatory. so, say, gwt wouldn't be an option because as far as I understand it would be slighty diffucult to combine WCF and gwt in one project, isn't it?

Comment: that depends on how you configure the WCF ;p If it is configured as a basicHttpBinding (as, IMO, it should be) then almost any platform/language/framework you can name should be able to connect without issue. That is just basic SOAP.

Comment: currently i'm using only named pipe, but  I will probably change binding to another. I want to have the ability to switch binding to whatever I want

Comment: some bindings are platform dependent; some are not. Keep that in mind ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF is very flexible.

WCF allows many transports like TCP, HTTP.  Over HTTP, it allows you to serialize into various formats such as SOAP, JSON etc...

So, the consumer of it can across multiple platforms.  Each platform has multiple frameworks and languages to consume SOAP, JSON, Sockets etc...

So, the answer is whatever client platform, framework and/or language that is best suited for the type of presentation you want to present.  To me, that's the deciding factor - not what framework the server is using to send data over the wire.  If you develop it right, the UI has no idea what the server framework is or how it comes across the wire.  If you code with MVC or MVVM, the model is concerned with interacting with the service.  So, you could replace your UI layer, model layer or server layer without affecting any other layer.  Loose coupling.

Of course, if you're coding both the server and the client, a lot can be said for using consistent languages and frameworks.  In that case, if it's C# your obvious choices are winforms and WPF/silverlight.

Comment: so should I use "WPF AND silverlight" or I should choose "WPF OR silverlight"?

Answer (score 0):

Any .net language can work with WCF (VB.NET, F#, etc) but c# is a good choice.

"display it to the user"? What kind of application are you creating? A standalone application (a "program") or a website?

If its just a standalone application, both winforms and wpf will do.

Comment: I would say that this is a standalone application which probably receive data via network from WCF in future (but via namedpipe for now). However if some library is better and more portable than another I would prefer more portable library. Probably one day I will run my application in web browser, who knows

Comment: well winforms or wpf are hardly considered a library, they are just part of the .net framework. So both will do equally in terms of portability.